# How to iterate on json data with sql/knexjs query

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, knex.js

I'm using postgresql db.I have a table named 'offers' which has a column 'validity' which contains the following data in JSON format:

```
[{"end_date": "2019-12-31", "program_id": "4", "start_date": "2019-10-27"}, 
{"end_date":"2020-12-31", "program_id": "6", "start_date": "2020-01-01"}, 
{"end_date": "2020-01-01", "program_id": "3", "start_date": "2019-10-12"}]
```

Now I want to get all records where 'validity' column contains:
program_id = 4 and end_date > current_date.

How to write SQL query or knexjs query to achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want all array elements from that JSON array as individual rows? Or just the rows from the table `offers` where at least one of the array elements matches your criteria?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  just the rows from the table offers where at least one of the array elements matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an EXISTS condition:

```
select o.*
from offers o
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(o.validity) as v(item)
              where v.item ->> 'program_id' = '3'
                and (v.item ->> 'end_date')::date > current_date)
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f53504179f1ea98b034dff334d48a5a7)

Comment: Thanks but its giving me some errors like 'cannot extract elements from a scalar' and 'syntax error at end of input'.Can you please look into it?

Comment: @ShaheryarAhmed: then you don't have a valid JSON value in your column.

Comment: hm right. Can you please suggest me some stuff where I can read more about iterating json with sql?